# Replace data in a partition of a table in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a use case where I have to **replace the data in a partition of a table** in BigQuery every time 15 mins. Are there any functions available in Bigquery similar to partition exchange in Bigquery or any provision to truncate data of a partition.

Comment: Have you checked DML for partitioned tables? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables
You could also overwrite partitioned table data using a load job: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data Could you provide more information on what would be your exact use case?

Comment: The requirement is load the partition of a table every fifteen minutes with new calculated values. Usually we truncate that partition before loading the data. Got the answer in the mentioned link i.e. DML for partitioned table.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer in the aforementioned link. I'll post an answer so that the community can benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your requirement to load new data every fifteen minutes into a partitioned table you could use [Data Manipulation Language (DML)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language).

In order to update rows in a partitioned table you could use the UPDATE statement as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables).

Also, in case that you wanted to overwrite partitions you could also use a load job using the CLI as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#using_a_load_job). Using --noreplace or --replace you can specify if you want to append or truncate the given partition.